# Spring batch parsing on different data

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

I have scenario where file have different type. File is divided into 3 part header body and footer. Header can be 2 type dipend on header size I need to use tokenizer and range to parse the content.

Same for the footer depending on body size and footer length need to parse footer content.

I went through PatternMatchingCompositeLineMapper and fixedlenghttokenizer but not find the way where we specify conditions for range and also share the body content in footer to check length

I am new in spring batch. Please help me with the same. Thanks in advance for any suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have override mapline method where I get content and line number and it will execute for each line.
Before execution of map line I build the tokenizer depending on content and it is working for me

Answer (score 0):

For such advanced file formats, you need a custom `ItemReader`.